# Close VS Code popup window function definition in editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

[popup window function definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgUG3.png)

As the image shows, when I'm in the function body, the function definition is shown in a popup window.

To resolve the problem, you can open `settings.json`, and add `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false` to it.

Comment: .... no. how do you get the wrong answer to your own problem?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the problem, you can open `settings.json`, and add

```
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false
```